# Unable to receive PushIO notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

I made an android app according to this guide: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCFA/android/step-by-step/

I have used standard xml configuration. I am able to register my device into the `PushIO` and this is my log:

```
D/pushio﹕ Google Play Services found, using GCM for notification service.
D/pushio﹕ mRegisteringNotificationPreferences: null,mScheduledNotificationPreferences: null
D/pushio﹕ Get All PushIO Preferences
D/pushio﹕ mPushIOPersistenceManagerMap: 0
D/pushio﹕ Scheduling a new registration in 15 seconds
I/Broadcast registered﹕ true
D/Activity﹕ #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
D/pushio﹕ Starting registration...
D/pushio﹕ Register - Request String: dt=xxx
D/pushio﹕ Registration with push.io servers successful!
```

The problem is, I never receive any notification.

On top of that, the PushIO manager from which I am pushing doesn't show any number of 'Sent' notifications, though it shows on top of the image, that it was sent. See picture (might be just a bug in the UI, not sure):
[image]

My `Manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.otoincreasedk.increasepushio">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.otoincreasedk.increasepushio.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <permission android:name="com.example.otoincreasedk.increasepushio.permission.PUSHIO_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.otoincreasedk.increasepushio.permission.PUSHIO_MESSAGE"/>
    <permission android:name="com.example.otoincreasedk.increasepushio.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:node="replace">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <receiver android:name="com.pushio.manager.PushIOBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action  android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.otoincreasedk.increasepushio" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="com.pushio.manager.PushIOActivityLauncher" android:exported="true" />
        <service android:name="com.pushio.manager.PushIOGCMIntentService" />
        <service android:name="com.pushio.manager.PushIOEngagementService" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
                <receiver
                    android:name="com.example.otoincreasedk.increasepushio.NotificationBroadcastReceiver"
                    android:exported="false">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action  android:name="com.example.otoincreasedk.increasepushio.PUSHIOPUSH"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
        -->

    </application>



</manifest>
```

My `MainActivity's` `onCreate` method:

```
// Instantiate the Push IO Manager:
PushIOManager pushIOManager = PushIOManager.getInstance(this);

// Ensure that any registration changes with Google get reflected with Push IO.
// Also registers for Broadcast Push Notifications (All Users).
pushIOManager.ensureRegistration();
```

Comment: Hey, u got any solution?

Comment: @Ondrej Tokar, I'm also facing the same problem. Did you get any solution?